# How to solve this equation with SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

In MathCad it looks like this:

[image]

How to solve it using python (scipy or sympy)?

Maybe something like this?

```
def fun(n):
    x, y, z = n
    return -0.7353 + 3.306 * np.absolute(0.706 - x) + 1.247 * np.absolute(0.7210 - y) - (0.89072 - 1.4829*x + 0.23239*y - z)
scipy.optimize.fsolve(fun, [1,1,1])
```

Comment: Have your code worked?

Comment: How are you solving for 3 unknowns with what looks like only 2 equations?

Comment: What exactly are you needing to use scipy for? All your variables are defined, so your function returns a scalar value without needing to `solve` for anything

Comment: >Have your code worked?
Code not worked.
> How are you solving for 3 unknowns with what looks like only 2 equations?
Ok, but MatCad is solve it

Comment: Mathcad gave *a* solution, but it is not unique.

Comment: You want to use `scipy.optimize.minimize` rather than `fsolve`.  Wrap the output of your function in `np.abs(...)` and it will find **one** of the **infinite** solutions to your equation.

Comment: @James it really looks like something strange with the variable z

Answer (score 2):

#### Code

The important thing (for this scipy.minimize based approach) is the quadratic penalization of the error (which is the difference of both sides). Of course there are other approaches, but be careful to bound the objective.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

fun = lambda x: ((-0.7353 + 3.306 * (abs(0.706 - x[0])) + 1.247 * (abs(0.721 - x[1]))) - \
                (0.89072 - 1.4829 * x[0] + 0.23239 * x[1] - x[2]))**2
x0 = [1, 1, 1]
res = minimize(fun, x0, tol=1e-6)
print(res)
```

#### Result

```
fun: 1.180300596982825e-18
hess_inv: array([[ 0.01850105, -0.02426119, -0.04300235],
 [-0.02426119,  0.23287182,  0.24090596],
 [-0.04300235,  0.24090596,  0.61570727]])
jac: array([  5.34881862e-08,   3.58270711e-08,   1.27283284e-08])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
nfev: 50
nit: 6
njev: 10
status: 0
success: True
x: array([ 0.69247018, -0.38146035, -0.90898925])
```

As mentioned in the comments, there is **no unique solution**. Your start-point and chosen algorithm decides what kind of solution you get.

The only relevant part is the **objective, which should approach zero!**